# Mockito Mock log4j appender is not invoked while running unit test

Tags: unit-testing, log4j, mockito, slf4j

I am trying to unit test the log statements generated in my code. I am using slfj, log4j and Mockito. I am using the similar code as below from the blog at
http://bloodredsun.com/2010/12/09/checking-logging-in-unit-tests/

When I run the test it throws exception saying that there are 0 invocations at line:

`verify(mockAppender).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());`

**Error Message**:

> Wanted but not invoked: mockAppender.doAppend();
>   -> at testClass.testLogAdviceAfterReturning(DpsOpsLoggerTest2.java:94) Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I see the logs printed on the console though. Request you to kindly help.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleThatLogsTest {

    @Mock
    private Appender mockAppender;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor captorLoggingEvent;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(mockAppender);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        LogManager.getRootLogger().removeAppender(mockAppender);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldConcatAndLog() {
        //given
        ExampleThatLogs example = new ExampleThatLogs();
        //when
        String result = example.concat("foo", "bar");
        //then
        assertEquals("foobar", result);

        verify(mockAppender).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());
        LoggingEvent loggingEvent = captorLoggingEvent.getValue();
        //Check log level
        assertThat(loggingEvent.getLevel(), is(Level.INFO));
        //Check the message being logged
        assertThat(loggingEvent.getRenderedMessage(), 
            is("String a:foo, String b:bar"));
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please give the error log

Comment: @AbdulManaf : I have updated the error message.

Comment: @JohnLiva: Can you show us what ExampleThatLogs does? How does it initalize its Logger?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to emulate your case ,At my end it is working fine

//Log Util

```
        public class LogUtil{

        final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogUtil.class);

        public static Log`enter code here`ger getLogger()
        {
            return logger;
        }
```

//class

```
public class RunMe {

        public String runMe(String parameter) {

            LogUtil.getLogger().info("This is info : " + parameter);
            return "In runner " + parameter;

        }
    }
```

// Unit Test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoggerTest {

    @Mock
    private Appender mockAppender;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor captorLoggingEvent;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        LogUtil.getLogger().addAppender(mockAppender);
        }

    @Test
    public void shouldConcatAndLog() {

        RunMe runner=new RunMe();
        String result=runner.runMe("XYZ");
        assertEquals("In runner XYZ",result);
       verify(mockAppender).doAppend((LoggingEvent) captorLoggingEvent.capture());
      LoggingEvent logevent= (LoggingEvent) captorLoggingEvent.getValue();
      assertThat(logevent.getLevel(), is(Level.INFO));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        LogUtil.getLogger().removeAllAppenders();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit outdated, but I was struggling with this too. I was logging statements at DEBUG level in the class under test. My configuration in logback.xml for the class under test was set to INFO. Changing my logging statement to INFO allowed the test to pass. In addition, I also read [this](https://gist.github.com/bloodredsun/a041de13e57bf3c6c040) Github post that is really concise and a clean implementation of testing log output. Hope others will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use This
verify(mockAppender,atLeastOnce()).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());
in the verify method 2nd argument tells how many times you want to mock so
In your case its zero
You can refer this also:-https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).